# how to see Bottle uncaught exceptions in uwsgi logs

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi, bottle

Seems that Bottle doesn't forward uncaught exceptions to uwsgi logger, at least in my case.
Config : Debian testing, python 3.4.1, uwsgi 2.0.6, bottle 0.12.0

uwsgi:

```
enable-thread = true
workers = 4
(...various other config options...)
logto = /var/log/mylogfile.log
```

in my app code, debug set to True:

```
debug(True)
```

suppose i have a Object.method(arg1, arg2), if in one route if put:

```
Object.method()    # without argument
```

it logs nothing.
if i catch exception it works

```
try:
    Object.method()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

it gives : method() missing 2 requred positional agurments: 'arg1' and 'arg2'
as we would expect.

question : how to log uncaught exceptions (anywhere in fact, not necessarely on uwsgi log, i just want to see those exception without having to catch them on per case basis)

it's been days i'm on this problem, so any help greatly appreciated !

---

**ANSWER :**

after days and posting it here, i found the solution within minutes...
problem was that route request was made via AJAX call, so Bottle was taking care of uncaught exception and showing via HTTP response **without** passing it to uwsgi.
on AJAX request, i couldn't see it.
trick is to set

```
Bottle(catchall=False)
```

to force Bottle app to pass uncaught exceptions to uwsgi (it won't show it via HTTP request)
it works even without

```
debug(True)
```

Comment: You could answer it yourself and accept your own answer.